# Twitter Fabric Login iOS How To Change App Keys

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, twitter

The Fabric Twitter Login for iOS is showing an odd "Created By Fabric ... Deleted App" when someone is asked to put in credentials in the oAuth webview that pops up. In attempts to fix this, I've tried to regenerate the api keys in the fabric web admin interface, and I'm shown this message:

> Your keys have been regenerated. Please update them in your app.

But, I have no idea how I update them in my app. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keys are in the info plist of your app. All under a key fabric.
See the screenshot for how it looks:

[image: info plist section]

Comment: Awesome, found it. Any idea why in the first place I get the odd "created by fabric" thingy? Added screenshot to question to clarify the problem.